# How do you mock typeorm's getManager using testdouble?

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, typeorm, testdoublejs

When creating unit tests for [typeorm](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm), I want to mock my connection to the database so that I can run unit tests without actually ever connecting to the DB (a good thing!)

I see [places](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/171#issuecomment-347724850) where people have mocked typeorm's repositories using [testdouble](https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js) (which I am also using), but I am trying to do this with [getManager](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/working-with-entity-manager.md) and am having an issue figuring out how to make it work.

Here's an example. I have a class that, in the constructor, creates an EntityManager by using getManager() for a connection called 'test':

```
export class TestClass {
    constructor() {
        const test: EntityManager = getManager('test');
    }
}
```

Now I want to test that I can simply create this class. Here's a sample (using mocha, chai, and testdouble):

```
describe('data transformer tests', () => {
    it('can create the test class', () => {

        // somehow mock getManager here

        const testClass: TestClass = new TestClass();
        chai.expect(testClass, 'could not create TestClass').to.not.be.null;
    });
});
```

When I try this, I get this error message from typeorm:

```
ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "test" was not found.
```

Here are some of the things I've tried to mock getManager:

```
td.func(getManager)
```

same error as above.

```
td.when(getManager).thenReturn(td.object('EntityMananger'));
```

gets the message:

```
Error: testdouble.js - td.when - No test double invocation call detected for `when()`.
```

Any ideas what the magic sauce is here for mocking `getManager`?

Comment: Just to add, I never found an answer with this, and wound up using sinon for my mocks, and it worked just fine.

Comment: Are you not supposed to actually make the call in `td.when()`? i.e _"when called with x then return y"_; something along those lines: `td.when(getManager(x)).thenReturn(y)`. I think this is what the error message is saying. You need to tell TD what to return for a given function call.

Answer (score 8):

I tried `sinon` instead of `testdouble`. I created a [small repository](https://github.com/YegorZaremba/typeorm-mock-unit-testing-example), which shows how you can mock database for your blazing unit-tests :)

I tried to cover all `TypeORM` test cases using `Jest` and `Mocha`

Example

```
import * as typeorm from 'typeorm'
import { createSandbox, SinonSandbox, createStubInstance } from 'sinon'
import { deepEqual } from 'assert'

class Mock {
  sandbox: SinonSandbox

  constructor(method: string | any, fakeData: any, args?: any) {
    this.sandbox = createSandbox()

    if (args) {
      this.sandbox.stub(typeorm, method).withArgs(args).returns(fakeData)
    } else {
      this.sandbox.stub(typeorm, method).returns(fakeData)
    }
  }

  close() {
    this.sandbox.restore()
  }
}

describe('mocha => typeorm => getManager', () => {
  let mock: Mock

  it('getAll method passed', async () => {
    const fakeManager = createStubInstance(typeorm.EntityManager)
    fakeManager.find.resolves([post])

    mock = new Mock('getManager', fakeManager)

    const result = await postService.getAll()
    deepEqual(result, [post])
  })

  afterEach(() => mock.close())
})
```

Comment: Yeah, sinon works well for this. I don't think it is possible with `testdouble`. Not marking as accepted answer because it doesn't use testdouble.

Comment: FYI been using this for some time, but it stopped working correctly when typeorm released v0.2.35.